# Should I select "Leave Open" if a moderator had commented on (but didn't close) a post?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, vote-to-close, moderators

When reviewing close-votes on posts, every now and then we would encounter questions where a moderator had left one or more comments, but didn't close the question.

Given that the moderator hadn't closed it, it should mean that the moderator didn't find the question close-worthy.

Is it okay to choose "Leave open" based on that?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken a mod's close votes are unilateral; meaning that a single VTC from them closes the question.  I would not be surprised if they therefore comment, rather than VTC, as they don't want to unilaterally close. I, for example, often do this when trying to push a user to a duplicate but where there is a little ambiguity to whether it will answer the question (normally due to clarity issues in the question); as my single VTC would close the question. I therefore mimic the Duplicate suggestion comment.

Comment: It could also mean the mod didn't know the topic, didn't read the question, forgot to vote, or just didn't feel like it. When you are reviewing it in the queue, you have to make the decision yourself.

Comment: "*it should mean that the moderator didn't find the question close-worthy.*" or they weren't completely sure. I don't know about mods but some times I'm not completely convinced a question is a duplicate. Since I have a gold hammer, one vote for me would close it. So I tend to comment with a link and see if others agree. So, I'd try to vote third, rather than overrule others. Perhaps some mods also apply a similar behaviour - they don't want to immediately close, so leave others to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes moderators will not VTC merely to avoid having to cast a binding vote. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suppose that's why moderators who VTC are often the third close voter).

Also, moderators can sometimes make mistakes. You're perfectly free to disagree with the moderator's assessment of the question and vote differently than them.

So, the mere fact that a moderator didn't VTC doesn't mean that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 16):

Judge the post on its merits.

That's all there is to it.

If **you** think it should be closed, vote to close. If not, then don't.

If unsure, remember to skip.